# boost range algorithm implementation & complexity guarantees

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

I'm considering using some of the [boost range algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms.html) in my project. Primarily to make my code less verbose, e.g. replacing

```
std::sort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
std::unique(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
```

with

```
boost:unique(boost::sort(vec));
```

My main reservation is that I'm unsure if boost algorithms use the same implementations as standard library equivalents, or even have the same complexity guarantees. I've checked the source code of a few of the boost algorithms, and they do indeed just call the standard library equivalents, but is this **guaranteed**?

Comment: Why not check documentation before delving into source code? [boost::sort](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/sort.html), [boost::unique](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/unique.html)

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot to clarify, I'm mostly interested if the boost algorithms are required to call standard library versions (rather than providing an independent implementation).

Comment: No, they are not required to do that. They **usually** do so, but if they detect if, for example, current implementation does not suit complexity constraints or has bugs, it might fall back to own imlementation. Another example is calling `boost::iota` on C++03 compiler (`std::iota` is a C++11 feature)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Boost.Range documentation specifies the complexity guarantees of each function. But there is nothing which requires that these guarantees must be provided by using a standard library equivalent iterator-based algorithm.

For example, `boost::sort` is required, according to the documentation, to provide an `O(N log(N))` sort operation. It has no requirements of stability for equal elements. Since these are the same requirements as `std::sort`, it *could* be implemented by calling that function. But nothing in Boost *requires* this.